# Hide images from gallery - Show only in own application?

Tags: java, android

How do I take pictures with the camera and ensure that the taken pictures are only visible from within my own application. ie I don't want the pictures to appear in the gallery app?

EDIT:
Can someone show some code on how to set this path such that when the picture is taken and the user presses save in the camera app, it saves to getFilesDir path ?

Comment: well its  because its a food app, so the pictures should not get mixed up with the familiy pictures.. pretty annoying to scroll through 100 dishes before getting to the next non-food picture, right?

Comment: I have tried storing image as blob in sqlite db, but the image still appears in the gallery... I think I should go for storing uris in database instead..

Comment: My gallery is separated by folders, so if you just make your own folder on the SD card when the user is in their gallery they'll see FoodPics or whatever as a folder and skip past it to what they're looking for. I am with Andrew an application able to take pictures and hide them from the system would get deleted from my phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I take pictures with the camera and ensure that the taken pictures are only visible from within my own application.

Don't store them someplace that is indexed by the `MediaScanner`. That could be in your application-local file store (e.g., `getFilesDir()`), or on external storage in a directory that has a `.nomedia` file.

> I have tried storing image as blob in sqlite db, but the image still appears in the gallery

Either you did not store the "image as blob in sqlite db", or the images also existed in the file system somewhere. I am very confident that an "image as blob in sqlite db" did not get indexed.

Comment: Can someone show some code on how to set this path such that when the picture is taken and the user presses save in the camera app, it saves to getFilesDir path ?

Comment: @Arcadia: You would need to directly use the `Camera` object. If you use the `Intent`, the camera application has no rights to write to your app's `getFilesDir()` directory.